# Cannot Input Text into HTML input element using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have HTML which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="USERNAME.DUMMY.DUMMY.1" value="" id="USERNAME.DUMMY.DUMMY" class="username" size="25" autocomplete="Off">
```

I am trying to insert text to this input element after loading it. Her is my Robot script:

```
Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
Sleep    ${wait}
Input Text    id=USERNAME.DUMMY.DUMMY    ${text}
```

But it is never able to find the ID. I have tried the same with class and name attributes but none of them work. This element is not under an iFrame.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Check if the username field is inside a shadow element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
input text    //*[@id="USERNAME.DUMMY.DUMMY"]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).